# Drawing a GridView on a Canvas in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to draw a GridView on a Canvas in an Android app as follows, but nothing is displayed on screen.

```
            int width = 400;
    int height = 400;

            private String[] numbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);     

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);

    GridView gridview = new GridView(MainActivity.this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);


    layout.addView(gridview);

    layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    layout.draw(canvas);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Can anyone please suggest what's wrong here?

Thanks.
James

Answer (score 0):

Maybe main LinearLayout not added activity contentView. Because it' s dinamically created and than not attach other views.